# can ModbusRtu.h library send data from slave to master using modbus(RS485) module?

Tags: rs485, modbus, rs232

i am using ModbusRtu.h library for modbus protocol. it works for sending data from master to  slave but it can not send data from slave to master.

master code:

```
#include <ModbusRtu.h>
  #define SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE 64
// data array for modbus network sharing
uint16_t au16data[26];
uint8_t u8state;

/**
 *  Modbus object declaration
 *  u8id : node id = 0 for master, = 1..247 for slave
 *  port : serial port
 *  u8txenpin : 0 for RS-232 and USB-FTDI 
 *               or any pin number > 1 for RS-485
 */
Modbus master(0,Serial1,8); // this is master and RS-232 or USB-FTDI

/**
 * This is an structe which contains a query to an slave device
 */
modbus_t telegram;

unsigned long u32wait;

void setup() {
  Serial1.begin( 19200 ); // baud-rate at 19200
  Serial.begin( 19200 ); // baud-rate at 19200
//  master.start();
 master.begin();
  master.setTimeOut( 2000 ); // if there is no answer in 2000 ms, roll over
  u32wait = millis() + 1000;
  u8state = 0; 
}

void loop() {

    telegram.u8id = 2; // slave address
    telegram.u8fct = 3 ; // function code (this one is registers read)3
    telegram.u16RegAdd = 0; // start address in slave 1     slave array index 0 dhora
    telegram.u16CoilsNo = 2; // number of elements (coils or registers) to read 4  //master array er koyta(not start from 0) value show korba
    telegram.au16reg = au16data; // pointer to a memory array in the Arduino
    int x = master.poll(); // check incoming messages
    Serial.print("x: ");
    Serial.println(x);
                if (master.getState() == COM_IDLE)
                {
                   master.query( telegram ); // send query (only once)

                }
Serial.print("Recieve: ");
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i += 1)
      {
        Serial.print(au16data[i]);
        Serial.print(",");
      }
      Serial.println("");              
}
```

slave code:

```
#include <ModbusRtu.h>
#define SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE 64
// data array for modbus network sharing
//uint16_t au16data[26] = {
//  3, 1415, 9265, 4, 2, 7182, 28182, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1 };
uint16_t au16data[26] = {4,17,89};
int led = 13;
/**
 *  Modbus object declaration
 *  u8id : node id = 0 for master, = 1..247 for slave
 *  port : serial port
 *  u8txenpin : 0 for RS-232 and USB-FTDI 
 *               or any pin number > 1 for RS-485
 */
Modbus slave(2,Serial1,8); // this is slave @1 and RS-232 or USB-FTDI

void setup() {
  Serial1.begin( 19200 ); // baud-rate at 19200
  Serial.begin( 19200 ); // baud-rate at 19200
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  slave.begin();
  //slave.start();
}

void loop() {

  slave.poll( au16data, 26 );

   Serial.print("Recieve: ");
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i += 1)
      {
        Serial.print(au16data[i]);
        Serial.print(",");
        if(au16data[3] == 1)
        {
          digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
         // Serial.println("in");
        }
         if(au16data[3] == 2)
        {
           digitalWrite(led, LOW);
           //Serial.println("else");
        }
      }
         Serial.println("");

       memset(au16data, 0, 26 * sizeof(uint16_t)); // recieveLargeArray = {}
}
```

Comment: and which one of the many ModbusRTU libraries do you use?

Comment: i used this library https://github.com/smarmengol/Modbus-Master-Slave-for-Arduino/find/master